# Simple c++ ATM (can't store balance variable input)

Tags: c++

I'm making a simple c++ atm program, but I'm having trouble with getting the balance to change after I make a deposit or withdraw.

```cpp
// C++ ATM

#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

int main()
{
    bool card_is_inserted = false;
    double balance = 0.0;
    //double new_balance = balance;


    // HOME

    //Starts over if variable is false
    while (card_is_inserted == false)
    {
        cout << "Wellcome to Well's Fargo ATM " << '\n'
        << "Insert card Yes or No"<< endl;
        string request;
        getline(cin,request);

        // Function is needed for aceppting different no's and yes's
        //-=-=-=--=-==--=-=-==-==-=--==--=-=-
        // loads atm
        if (request == "yes")
        {
            cout << "Alright, Your current balance is:" << endl
            << balance << endl;
            card_is_inserted = true;
        }

        // home
        string option = "cancel";

        while (card_is_inserted == true)
        {
            cout << "Would you like to withdraw or deposit? (Cancel)"<< endl;
            getline(cin,option);

            double cash_ = 0;

            if (option == "deposit")
            {
                cout << "How much money would you like to deposit?" << endl;
                cin >> cash_;
                double new_deposit_balance = balance + cash_;

                cout << "You placed: $" << cash_ << endl
                    << "Your New Balance is: $" << new_deposit_balance << endl;
            }

            if (option == "withdraw")
            {
                cout << "How much money would you like to withdraw?" << endl;
                cin >> cash_;
                double new_witdraw_balance = balance - cash_;

                if(balance <= 0)
                {
                    cout << "You don't have: $" << cash_ << endl;
                }
                else
                {
                cout << "You toke: $" << cash_ << endl
                << "Your New Balance is: $"<< new_witdraw_balance << endl;
                }
            }

            if (option == "cancel")
            {
                cout << "Ok, bye" << endl;
                card_is_inserted = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

example: I type yes to make a deposit(or withdraw) and then place a simple double like 12.50 then it shows me my current balance which will be 12.50; afterward  I want to make a withdraw of 12.00 with .50 left. But I cant because the balance variable didn't store my previous value which was 12.50. I tried making "double new_balance = balance"  but doesn't work like in swift.

Comment: Just an advanced topic note. `double` is never used for money amounts where precision is needed, like money-balance, as `double` can't represent all common monetary amounts precisely, like for example `0.1` is stored in `double` as `0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625` (and that's the closest you may get to `0.1` with `double`).  (and these errors may accumulate, so you if you would deposit 10e18 times 0.1 money (and withdraw 1.0 every tenth time), your balance would be not expected zero, but +0.5 (or +5, not sure where 10e18 lands)).

Comment: I saw that but not sure how to go about fixing it. right now I'm trying to limit the number of characters typed so no one will type 9, 100 times. If you could give me a hint that be great.

Comment: It's not trivial topic, at the moment don't worry about it much, just read in spare time probably [this](http://floating-point-gui.de/) and make sure you have full understanding how computers work with integral types (how amount of bits defines min/max values), then you can try to learn how FP IEEE 754 works, so you fully understand the computational limits of computers, and how to order arithmetic operations to minimize propagation of partial errors into total error. And while outputting balance, set up formatter to 2 decimal places: `cout.precision(2);` That will hide errors for some time.

Comment: If you would work on serious app, consider writing full `Money` class, which can use only integer types for amounts (`int64_t` should cover most of the mankind needs, although when in doubt, check overflow conditions), and also have currency code and basic plus/minus/... operations. At that point currency like USD can work with scale 100, i.e. internal integer 457 will be displayed as $4.57, and the smallest possible amount is $0.01. This may be good exercise in C++ programming and unit testing. Also there are libraries for arbitrary precision math, use those if you need even better precision.

Answer (score 1):

You are not setting `balance` to `new_witdraw_balance` or `new_deposit_balance`.

`double new_deposit_balance = balance + cash_;` doesn't set the `balance` value because you are bring in the value of `balance`, but you are not assigning the outcome of `balance + cash_` to `balance`.

You need to put something like `balance = new_witdraw_balance;` and `balance = new_deposit_balance;` at the end of each `if` after `cout` statement.

```
if(option == "deposit")
{
    cout << "How much money would you like to deposit?" << endl;
    cin >> cash_;
    double new_deposit_balance = balance + cash_;

    cout << "You placed: $" << cash_ << endl << "Your New Balance is: $" << new_deposit_balance << endl;

    balance = new_deposit_balance; // this
}

if(option == "withdraw")
{
    cout << "How much money would you like to withdraw?" << endl;
    cin >> cash_;
    double new_witdraw_balance = balance - cash_;

    if(balance <= 0)
    {
        cout << "You don't have: $" << cash_ << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "You toke: $" << cash_ << endl << "Your New Balance is: $"<< new_witdraw_balance << endl;
        balance = new_witdraw_balance; // and this
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The line `double new_deposit_balance = balance + cash_;` only assigns the new balance to `new_deposit_balance`, but then you don't do anything with that variable (except print the value). If you want the new balance to persist, you actually need to modify `balance`, not `new_deposit_balance`, so something like `balance = balance + cash_;` or `balance += cash_;`.

The variable `double new_deposit_balance` only exists in the if-block it's defined in, so once you leave the if-block, you lose the information in `new_deposit_balance`. On the other hand, since `balance` is defined outside your if-blocks and while-loops, its value will persist throughout your ATM operations.

Of course, you'd also need to apply the same fix to `new_witdraw_balance`.